# Scraping E-Commerce sites and aggregating same products

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to learn about web-scraping and as an application I figured I'd build an aggregator that crawls retailers for certain products and sets up a price comparison for the same product from different retailers.

As I got started on this I realized exactly how large a tasks this is.

First, I need to crawl sites that have various formats for not only their DOM structures but also slightly different names for the same products and formats for item's prices and prices for items on sale.

Second, After I've somehow decoded the DOM for x number of sites (doing it for one or two is easy but I want to make the crawler scalable!) and fetched the data for various items. I need to be able to compare the different names of same products so I can compare the differing prices (convert them to the same currency, check if the returned price is the original/on-sale price, etc...) between retailers.

I am trying to write my crawlers using Scrapy but can someone recommend an approach for how to adapt the crawler for a variety of retailers and if there are any libraries/approaches that would work well for the second problem of comparing like(unlike) items?

Comment: It’s usually better to keep questions separate. You are asking at least two quite-different questions here, making your post a bit too broad.

Comment: I see I'll break them up and ask separately

Answer (score 0):

For comparison you can convert strings of product names to lists, compare them and put a threshold to determine whether two products are same or not.